# Conevrt chararray to Date and add duration in Pig

Tags: apache-pig, datetime-format

Iam new to `Pig` and I have a sample test data of 500 KB which I need to multiply several times to make the file size bigger for some test purpose. The single row in my data is as follows:

```
(   card_description:chararray,
    transaction_date:chararray,
    merchant_name:chararray,
    merchant_city:chararray,
    transaction_amount:float
 ) ;
```

I want to simply change the `transaction_amount` and `transaction_date` for each row several times and then join all the results to make a single big file.
I am stuck in trying to change the `transaction_date`.
The date value in the file is

> 27/05/2010 00:00

```
r1 = FOREACH data GENERATE card_description,ToDate(transaction_date),merchant_name,merchant_city,
                                  ROUND(RANDOM()*5)*transaction_amount;

result =union data,r1;
```

In order to alter the transaction datei want to use `AddDuration` function, but in trying to convert `chararray` to `date`, I am facing format related issues and unable to understand the solution.

Can someone guide?

Answer (score 2):

After checking out the ways you can invoke [`ToDate`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/func.html#to-date), currently you are invoking [`ToDate`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/func.html#to-date) as:

```
ToDate(milliseconds)
ToDate(iosstring)
```

And your format is not in milliseconds, nor follows the [ISO 8601 format](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime). You should be invoking it like:

```
ToDate(userstring, format)
```

Where `format` is a pattern string that follows [these rules](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Therefore, `ToDate` should be called like:

```
-- For a 12hr clock
ToDate(transaction_date, "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm")

-- For a 24hr clock
ToDate(transaction_date, "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm")
```

---

For [`AddDuration`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/func.html#add-duration), remember that the second parameter you provide to it must be a string in the [ISO 8601 format](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime). Make sure to read the link so you format the string correctly.